# train multiples observations from the same person in caret

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, caret

I have data where persons were give four different tasks under three different conditions (intensities).

The data looks like this:

```
Person   intensity  task1 task2 task3 task4 outcome
     1         low      5     7     6     9    23.2
     1      medium      4     5     5     7    34.2
     1        high      3     3     2     5    66.1
     2         low      8     9     8     8    34.7
     2      medium      7     8     7     8    78.1
     2        high      5     5     6     5    56.1
```

I want to predice `outcome` based on the results of the four tasks and intensity. However, it should be taken into account that some people generally perform better at all intensities compared to others which is also reflected in the outcome value. How can this be achieved, I'm using the `caret` package.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches here and the best one would depend on how you are going to use the model:

- you could fit different models for different intensities
- you could fit one model and make new predictors for each intensity (e.g. `task1_low`, `task1_medium`) etc.

In those cases, you can train/tune as usual.

If you fit any models with multiple records from the same person (in different rows), you are probably going to want to make your own resampling indices so that a person is the experimental unit. Those independent "chunks" of data should not be split apart into modeling and holdout sets. To do that, you could generate CV or bootstrap resamples for each patient and then use the `index` and `indexOut` arguments of `trainControl` to determine which rows of the data should go into modeling and holdout.

Max